# Check condition on content page - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a page called. `content-home-page.php` i want to check this page.

```
if( is_page_template( 'content-home-page.php' ) ) // Not working
{ }
```

how can i check it? Above page is not a template page.

Comment: Use [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)